# MySQL Cluster and big blobs

Tags: mysql

I decided to use a MySQL Cluster for a bigger project of mine. Beside storing documents in a simple table scheme with only three indexes, a need to store information in the size of 1MB to 50MB arise. Those informations will be serialized custom tables being aggregats of data feeds.

How will be those information be stored and how many nodes will those information hit? I understand that with a replication factor of three those information will be written three times and I understand that there are coordinator nodes (named differently) so I ask myself what will be the impact storing those information?

Is it right that I understand that for a read a cluster will send those blobs to three servers (one requested the information, one coordinator and one data server) and for a write it is 5 (1+1+3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking MySQL only supports NoOfReplicas=2 right now, using 3 or 4 is generally not supported and not very well tested, this is noted here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html#ndbparam-ndbd-noofreplicas

"The maximum possible value is 4; currently, only the values 1 and 2 are actually supported."

As also described in the above URL, the data is stored with the same number of replicas as this setting.  So with NoOfReplicas=2, you get 2 copies.  These are stored on the ndbd (or ndbmtd) nodes, the management nodes (ndb_mgmd) act as co-ordinators and the source of configuration, they do not store any data and neither does the mysqld node.

If you had 4 data nodes, you would have your entire dataset split in half and then each half is stored on 2 of the 4 data nodes.  If you had 8 data nodes, your entire data set would be split into four parts and then each part stored on 2 of the 8 data nodes.

This process is sometimes known as "Partitioning".  When a query runs, the data is split up and sent to each partition which processes it locally as much as possible (for example by removing non-matching rows using indexes, this is called engine condition pushdown, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/condition-pushdown-optimization.html) and then it is aggregated in mysqld for final processing (may include calculations, joins, sorting, etc) and return to the client.  The ndb_mgmd nodes do not get involved in the actual data processing in any way.

Data is by default partitioned by the PRIMARY KEY, but you can change this to partition by other columns.  Some people use this to ensure that a given query is only processed on a single data node much of the time, for example by partitioning a table to ensure all rows for the same customer are on a single data node rather than spread across them.  This may be better, or worse, depending on what you are trying to do.

You can read more about data partitioning and replication here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-nodes-groups.html

Note that MySQL Cluster is really not ideal for storing such large data, in any case you will likely need to tune some settings and try hard to keep your transactions small.  There are some specific extra limitations/implications of using BLOB which you can find discussed here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-cluster-excerpt/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-limitations-transactions.html

I would run comprehensive tests to ensure it is performing well under high load if you go ahead and ensure you setup good monitoring and test your failure scenarios.

Lastly, I would also strongly recommend getting pre-sales support and a support contract from Oracle, as MySQL Cluster is quite a complicated product and needs to be configured and used correctly to get the best out of it.  In the interest of disclosure, I work for Oracle in MySQL Support -- so you can take that recommendation as either biased or very well informed.

Comment: The cluster will not be that heavily utilized. Also it is only for storing information up to 10TB-100TB I guess. Having only two replicas (I thought the value to be the additional replicas) is a bit low in my opinion.

Comment: The large data chunks will not be accessed frequently. They are just for faster recovery and startup time once an application node (not a MySQL data node) starts cold or catches up.

Comment: In the end its cassandra + a mechanism of sharding and distributing other data along with a custom search engine.